# Credentials for mosquitto broker in Node-red?

Tags: node-red

I would be interested on using node-red output function to publish kind of payload.

I know that the command using mosquitto publisher the call would be like this

```
mosquitto_pub -h staging.thethingsnetwork.org -t '0807060504030201/devices/0102030405060708/down' -u 0807060504030201 -P 'I0f+e1W+CWgIiuIC4SjR5cpLxFZQfK2agDEpuCBpttI=' -m '{ "payload":"SGVsbG8gd29ybGQK","port":1,"ttl":"1h"}'
```

Thus I was wondering how to fill correctly those paremeters on the mosquitto publish function available in node-red, so far I have translated the previous call to the function as

```
-server: staging.thethingsnetwork.org

-client ID: blank

-username: 0807060504030201 

-password: I0f+e1W+CWgIiuIC4SjR5cpLxFZQfK2agDEpuCBpttI=
```

The field payload, will be injected from an input inject function where payload is as above and in json format.

Is that valid setup?

Thanks in advance,

REgards

EDIT suggestions of knolleary in images
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The MQTT nodes in Node-RED do not support passing in the broker details with the message, you must manually configure the MQTT broker node.

1. Add an MQTT output node and double click to edit it
2. In the 'Server' config option, click the pencil to add a new mqtt-broker config
3. In the mqtt-broker config dialog enter the various configuration options you've copied from the mosquitto command

Once that is configured and deployed, messages passed to the MQTT output node will get published to the broker, using the `payload` and `topic` properties of the message.

Comment: You appear to have entered 'mosquitto' in the server box - that should be the address of the server - `staging.thethingsnetwork.org`. Of course if that username/password you've shared are real you'll want to reset them as you've now revealed them to the internet.